# find boundary for lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I've got to prove the existence and uniqueness of a solution of
$y'(x)=sin(x^2y^2)$ with $y(0)=1$ in the rectangle $R=\{(x,y):|x|\leq 1, |y-1|\leq1\}$ in the intervall $[-1,1]$.

So after showing that $f(x,y)=sin(x^2y^2)$ is continuously differentiable  with $f_y(x,y)=2yx^2cos(x^2y^2)$, we can write : $|f_y(x,y)| \leq 2x^2y$ as
$|cos(z)| \leq  1$. 
Now my tutor has stated that it follows $|f_y(x,y)| \leq 2x^2y\leq 2\cdot 1 \cdot 4$..
Why he has written these numbers? I only come to $2\cdot1\cdot 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $x$ is given $$|x|\le 1$$ so $$x^2\le 1$$ for $y$ is given $$|y-1|\le 1$$ and this is equivalent with $$0\le y\le 2$$

Comment: so it should be $2\cdot 1 \cdot  2$ right?

Comment: yes i think so is it right